# multiple carousels on same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have used 3 bootstrap carousels in my same page. In third carousel I have added a text to display alone with slide image. My third carousel is exactly like [this -](http://www.bootply.com/eWhrznPHZq)

This is Jquery I have used for my carousels

```
    // Set carousel options
    $('#homepage-feature').carousel({
      interval: 8000 // 8 seconds vs. default 5
    });

    // Set carousel options
    $('#timetable-feature').carousel({
      interval: 10000 // 4 seconds vs. default 5
    });


$('#image-gallery-carousel').carousel({
  interval: 5000
});

$('#carousel-text').html($('#slide-content-0').html());

// When the carousel slides, auto update the text
$('#image-gallery-carousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', function (e) {
  var id = $('.item.active').data('slide-number');
  //alert(id);
  $('#carousel-text').html($('#slide-content-'+id).html());
});
```

All carousels are working but in third carousel the text is not working. If I add only third carousel then it is working. My problem is why its not working with other two?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have 3 carousels on the page, I'd suspect you are targeting the wrong `.item-active` (the first carousels one)

Try

```
// When the carousel slides, auto update the text
$('#image-gallery-carousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', function (e) {
  var id = $(this).find('.item.active').data('slide-number');
  //alert(id);
  $('#carousel-text').html($('#slide-content-'+id).html());
});
```

Comment: Every carousel has a child with class ".item.active". When you call $(".item.active"), jQuery returns all the elements with class ".item-active". Then when you call the var id = $(...).data("slide-number"), the variable only gets the first one (see http://jsfiddle.net/petetnt/U73bJ/). In my code, you take the carousel with id #image-gallery-carousel (which inside the function is $(this) and find the element that has ".item-active" with http://api.jquery.com/find/